# The result of the search query differs in the API and Shutterstock website

Tags: shutterstock

please help me.
The result of the search query differs in the API and Shutterstock website. 
What am I doing wrong?

API returns only 4 results, but at shutterstock - thousands
My code:

```
$queryFields = [
  "query" => "осень лес векторы"
];

$options = [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search?" . http_build_query($queryFields),
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "php/curl",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx"
  ],
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
];

$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

$decodedResponse = json_decode($response);

echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r( $decodedResponse ); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The default API access (Self Serve, or Free product) is limited to a subset of Shutterstock's library - only about 1 million images. That's why you only see 4 results for your search compared to the website. If you need access to more content, just reach out to the team - https://developers.shutterstock.com/contact-us